# Passing hidden params into url

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5

I have a rails application in which I would like to generate a url based on a parameter, but for that parameter to be hidden from public view. So essentially working like a POST request but being able to be typed in like a GET request.

For example using a QR reader I could have the address as `www.site.com/qr?lot_no=18007` but when a user scans the QR image it only shows `www.site.com/qr` but displays the results related to `lot_no=18007`.

Not sure if this is possible or not. But any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: As far as I know you can 1. Encrypt your qr code before send it or 2. Store it in the session hash

Comment: The Friendly id gem is your friend

Answer (score 0):

If all you want to do is to prevent it from showing up in the address bar of the browser, you could use `Rails.ajax` to make the request dynamically through Javascript.

That will at least hide it from casual inspection, but there is no way to suppress the parameters from the query string on a GET completely, so anyone looking at the Networks tab in the browser (for example) would still see them.

Another alternative would be to encrypt the parameter value.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the Friendly id gem may be of help here
The following is an example of it's use is

```
http://example.com/states/washington

instead of:

http://example.com/states/4323454
```

This is not going to work with a post request as you mention though. It is a way of using a get request that would normally send an id in the params hash to retrieve existing records.

The gem can be found here https://github.com/norman/friendly_id
It is well maintained and up to date

Comment: I have looked into this. It seems an interesting approach. Not sure if its the right one though. I can't seem to find any solution on disabling the id route though. For example `http://example.com/states/washington` is usable but so is `http://example.com/states/4323454`.

Comment: @yellowskull In my experience `http://example.com/states/4323454` redirects to `http://example.com/states/washington`, so, yes it is usable but not really visible.

Answer (score 0):

Configure different route for public facing URL, the URL should include encrypted lot id as a path param.

**routes.rb**

```
get '/view_lot/:id' => 'QrCodesController#view_lot`, as: :public_view_lot
```

now in `QrCodesController` add action `view_lot`

```
def view_lot
  encrypted_id = params[:id]
  id = decrypt_it(encrypted_id)
  @lot = Lot.find(id)
  render "your_template"
end
```

in you QR code generation, pass URL to above action with encrypted id like `public_view_lot_url(lot_id)`

Comment: Thanks Amit. Could you expand on your idea a bit more? What is decrypt_it?

Comment: you will write a method `decrypt_it` which will decrypt the id.